# Get file size (in bytes) on client side

Tags: javascript, plugins, file-upload, browser

I make multiple file uploading project, (Server language is PHP)

Especially, I need that before uploading, on client side, get files size in bytes.

what is today best cross browser solution/plugin for this?

I find `SWFUpload`, may be exists better solution? or use this `SWFUpload`?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 a file drag & drop event creates a `File` object which has a `.size` property.

Look in `ev.dataTransfer` for the list of `File` objects.